# Cakephp3 Associations of three tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the Three tables:

```
 - Samples
 - Tests
 - Results
```

My aim is to develop associations between them so that:

A **sample** can have *many* **tests** and a test can have *one* **result**.
(A sample has many tests and another sample can also has same tests, on the other hand a test has one result and the same test for another sample can have a different result. )

---

### Table Example:

Here is my Sample Table:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | Name    | Type  |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  | Sample1 | Type1 |
+----+---------+-------+
| 2  | Sample2 | Type2 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Here is my Tests Table:

```
    +----+---------+
    | ID | Name    |
    +----+---------+
    | 1  | Test1   |
    +----+---------+
    | 2  | Test2   |
    +----+---------+
```

Here is my Results Table:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 1.22  |
+----+-------+
| 2  | 909   |
+----+-------+
```

### What I've done so far:

I've combined the **samples** and **tests** table and created a separate table called **samples_tests**.

Here is the structure of **samples_tests** table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | sample_id | test_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 1  | 2         | 4       |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 2  | 3         | 4       |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 3  | 3         | 2       |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Both the sample_id and test_id are foreign keys.

Here is my association in *SamplesTable.php*

```
$this->belongsToMany('Tests', [
            'foreignKey' => 'sample_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'test_id',
            'joinTable' => 'samples_tests'
        ]);
```

Here is my association in *TestsTable.php*

```
$this->belongsToMany('Samples', [
            'foreignKey' => 'test_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'sample_id',
            'joinTable' => 'samples_tests',
            'dependent' => true,
            'cascadeCallbacks' => true
        ]);
```

Its working pretty fine, but now i have to introduce the results part and i'm stuck on how to define the associations now.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

As suggested by @CbNrZvWd I've tried this:

```
$table = $this->table('samples_tests_results', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => ['sample_id', 'test_id', 'result_id']]);
        $table
            ->addColumn('sample_id', 'integer', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addColumn('test_id', 'integer', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addColumn('result_id', 'integer', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addIndex(
                [
                    'result_id',
                ]
            )
            ->addIndex(
                [
                    'sample_id',
                ]
            )
            ->addIndex(
                [
                    'test_id',
                ]
            )
            ->create();

$this->table('samples_tests_results')
            ->addForeignKey(
                'result_id',
                'results',
                'id',
                [
                    'update' => 'RESTRICT',
                    'delete' => 'RESTRICT'
                ]
            )
            ->addForeignKey(
                'sample_id',
                'samples',
                'id',
                [
                    'update' => 'RESTRICT',
                    'delete' => 'RESTRICT'
                ]
            )
            ->addForeignKey(
                'test_id',
                'tests',
                'id',
                [
                    'update' => 'RESTRICT',
                    'delete' => 'RESTRICT'
                ]
            )
            ->update();
```

But doing so adds the following complexity:

When i add new sample, i also select tests from a multi select dropdown. But it also asks for results in order to successfully save sample.

What i went is to save the sample with tests and add the results later on whenever i want.

Answer (score 0):

Results and Tests have a one to one relation.

add a test_id field to your results table

then in ResultsTable initialize method set up the relation:

```
$this->hasOne('Results');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations

and you can store additional data in the samples_tests table:

`ID | sample_id | test_id | result_id`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

Comment: How doing so the results will make this statement true: 'a test has one result and the same test for another sample can have a different result.' ?

Comment: oh i overlooked that part. then maybe a samples_tests_results table would do the trick?

Comment: Naah, I've tried this too, but cakephp considers samples_tests as one table and results as another.

Comment: you can tell cake which table to use: e.g.: in MyTable->initialize() do $this->table('my_super_table');